# How are these molecules chiral and achiral?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality, symmetry

[image]

I always thought that a molecule couldn't be chiral if it had a plane of symmetry. Doesn't the chiral molecule here have symmetry diagonally across the OHs? 
The achiral one doesn't look symmetrical to me, so I also don't know how it is achiral.

Comment: Both of your structures (Fischer projections) are chiral. Read this to help you understand such structures. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48995/is-2r-3s-butane-2-3-diol-chiral/87415#87415

Comment: The one on the left has point symmetry (in the Fischer projection, not in reality), but point symmetry anyway is not relevant for chirality.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the **first molecule:** I understand that the simplistic Fischer projection - with all its bond depicted by solid lines - can be very confusing at first glance in determining optical activity. You may believe it to be optically inactive, hoping for a center of symmetry to exist, but it is not so.

You must keep in mind how the **molecule actually exists in 3d**! Recall the rules of Fischer projection, the horizontal bonds project outward, while the vertical bonds extend inward. Hence, the molecule would actually look like this:

[image]

Now, I hope you can tell, there is neither any center of symmetry nor any plane of symmetry here. Hence, the molecule is **chiral.**

PS: Your second molecule is chiral by similar logic, as also mentioned in the comments, and as you yourself noted.