# Optical activity of tartaric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, isomers, symmetry

The *meso*-form of tartaric acid is optically inactive due to the plane of symmetry. But how are these forms able to show optical activity when the σ-bonds can freely rotate, which can change the configuration of the atoms?

[image]

Comment: Bond rotation doesn't change the fact that the molecule is still overall chiral and lacking in symmetry.

Comment: In other words, bond rotation ***can't*** change the configuration of the atoms.

Comment: @Nivedita Chowdhury: You are confused with conformation with configuration. There are no bond breaking with free rotation to change the configuration. yet, each isomer has infinite conformers due to rotation.

Comment: Consider the R,R-acid. Cut the central C-C bond with your magical chemical scissors. Now you have two tetrahedral objects that are identical in all respects. The fact that they happen to "dock" together is immaterial. After all, they are objects before they are chemical entities. The same holds for the S,S-acid.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/38989/9961